# Using SignalR azure service to communicate between 2 angular apps

Tags: .net, angular, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a SignalR hub on azure and I would like to use it for a simple chat between two Angular apps (one with backend in core other in .netframework)

So far I was able to connect (from both apps) to hub and use the connection for chat inside app.
But I am unable to trigger event from one app to client on the other app.

Is there some sort of hub client splitting based on app that is connecting ? If so - is there a way to disable it?

(Simply put I would like for any client that connects to a hub (no matter the app he is using) to be in the same pool)

Not sure if this matters but .netframework app uses hubproxy and core does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can send information between backends using by .Net SignalRClient

where string hubUrl= https://backendUrl.com/yourHub

```
public class SignalRClient: ISignalRClient
{
    private readonly HubConnection _connection;

    public SignalRClient(string hubUrl)
    {
        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(hubUrl)
            .Build();
    }

    public async Task ConnectAsync()
    {
        await _connection.StartAsync();
    }

    public async Task DisconnectAsync()
    {
        // await _connection.StopAsync();
        await _connection.DisposeAsync();
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(string method)
    {
        await _connection.InvokeAsync(method);
    }
}
```